# interpolation for time series data

Tags: r

I have e.g. time series climate data
Date 15/04/2013, 22/04/2013, 07/05/2013, 14/05/2013
and corresponding temperature 1,4,6,7 degree

I want to calculate temperature for each day from 15/04 to 14/05/2013, by linear interpolation.
could anyone please do it in R, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it

```
library(lubridate)
Date <- dmy(c("15/04/2013", "22/04/2013", "07/05/2013", "14/05/2013"))
temperature <- c(1,4,6,7)

New_temp <- approx(temperature, Date)
```

your temperature for each day will be

```
New_temp$x
```